# Expresso Store: Order items by channel?

Tags: expresso-store

I have a channel for each product type, e.g. breakfast, snacks, starters. When viewing the order using the {checkout} tag and the {items} variable, how can I order by channel?

Thanks for any ideas.
Lee

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change the order of the `{items}` loop in the checkout tag.

If you need to do this, the best method would be to use the native `{exp:query}` tag to find all items for a particular order, and sort them by the channel (or whatever else you want).